# what is the best way to implement access token in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.5

I am working on a project with play framework 2.5 which provides API service for developers.

I now want to implement access token with play framework in order to control the access of the server APIs.

I have implemented app key and app secret already. Can anyone please advices how to generate the access tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaWebTokens(jwt) which will provide you unique key always ,

```
public String getJWT(){
     Date now = new Date();
     long t = now.getTime();
     Date expirationTime = new Date(t + 1300819380);    

     return Jwts.builder()
          .setSubject("any subject")
          .setIssuedAt(now)
          .setExpiration(expirationTime)
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "username")
          .compact();
}
<--! to validate jwt -->
public boolean validateJWT(String jwt){
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("username").parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: How the client can use the token generated to communicate with the cloud?Does the client needs to call an api to get the token and then use the token to call the other api?

Comment: Store the token in local of web browser and add it to http header for every call , whenever you call the API ,verify whether the token is valid or not and process the request further

Comment: Thanks, when the token gets expired, does it need a refresh token in order to request a new one?

Comment: On expiry user should login again , on login this token should be generated and stored